# My Centre can be found in North Yorkshire

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

> If I score on myself, it's written in stone. 
>   I will act badly when given a bone. 
>   If it's handed to me, I'm likely to drop. 
>   But if I'm allowed, I'll avenge my pop.

**What am I?** 
**In your answer, please explain each line and the title.**

Comment: Does this puzzle need the [knowledge] tag?

Comment: @shoover, good point. A little bit of specific knowledge is useful (although not a lot) and I've added the wordplay tag too.

Comment: After reading the explanation for the "score on myself" part, I'd have to say this definitely requires the knowledge tag.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you..

> HAM? All the puzzle lines, including the title, refer to a word that contains the letters 'ham'.

If I score on myself, it's written in stone.

> Scoring against yourself in football is an "own goal", abbreviated to 'OG' - and *Ogham* is an ancient form of writing consisting of lines which were engraved (or 'scored') into stone. Thanks to @Tom

I will act badly when given a bone.

> "*Hambone*" is a slang word for a bad actor, sometimes abbreviated to simply "ham".

If it's handed to me, I'm likely to drop.

> Someone who drops things easily is said to be "*ham-handed*" (or "ham-fisted" (from @Jafe)

But if I'm allowed, I'll avenge my pop.

> "Let" means "allow", and the Shakespeare character *Hamlet* avenged the death of his father.

My Centre can be found in North Yorkshire

> 'Centre' is synonomous with 'middle', and *Middleham* is in North Yorkshire (also from @Jafe)

Comment: It's not correct but you are so so close. Keep thinking along these lines and think about using wordplay.

Comment: @hexomino how about now?

Comment: +1 Yes, correct answer. The explanation for the first two lines is not quite right (the second is close to the mark but not bang on).

Comment: Second line is now correct, first line is something different - think wordplay again.

Comment: Also, using your score, written in stone [rot13](https://www.rot13.com/) btunz.

Comment: Tom has it, as usual, but the prefix is an abbreviation for [scoring for the opponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Own_goal).

Comment: @MOehm Argh! So I was right about the own goal in the first place?!

Comment: Yes, your first show wasn't far off the mark. (But I didn't see the connection to Tom's solution when I read it earlier.)

Answer (score 5):

Partial, stolen from @Astralbee...

> ham

If it's handed to me, I'm likely to drop.

> ham-handed

But if I'm allowed, I'll avenge my pop.

> Hamlet

My centre can be found in North Yorkshire

> Middleham

Comment: +1, yes, correct! The first two lines still need an explanation.